# How to prevent wget from stoping on long php script

Tags: php, timeout, wget

Following code is executed in PHP

```
shell_exec('wget -q -T 0 -b -O "'.dirname(__FILE__).'/logs/log.txt" "'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/my/script.php" > /dev/null 2>&1');
```

After few hours script just stops without any reason. No error in log.txt, neither in apache errors. 
These lines should prevent such behaviour:

```
session_write_close();
ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
set_time_limit(0);
```

And i also added `echo(' '); flush();` from time to time, to make sure that apache doesn't kill script because of no output (it appeared in apache error logs).

Interesting hint is, when I add `ignore_user_abort(1);` at the beginning - script doesn't stop.

I know there are other ways to finish the script and collect the output, but what I'm looking for is the reason why wget abandons downloading, even when timeout is set to 0. Or maybe the reason is elsewhere?

Comment: if you can use `shell_exec` why won't you use `shell_exec('/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php');`

Comment: As you might read - I'm not interested in changing wget to other solution, but in finding actual reason. Running php via cli won't work when script are on diffrent severs, and has other disadvantages over wget in my particular case.

Comment: is it wget that kills the connection or is it the script that stops itself?

Comment: @Smok turn on wget debug reporting `--debug` and obviously log output somewhere `>debug.txt` and see what is happnening.

Comment: IMO it's only way, because there is lot possibilities for wget to abort. This can be www server issue too